# File save is not working on Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Ok, the code below is my code for reading in a file, that seems to work cross platform.

```
private function read(e:MouseEvent):void{
    file = File.applicationDirectory;
    var xmlFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("xml", "*.xml"); 
    file.browseForOpen("XML Documents", [xmlFilter]);
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
}
```

Next I have a button in mxml that launches this function:

```
private function write(e:MouseEvent):void{
    TextFile.write(xml.toString(), file.url);
    trace(file.url)
}
```

This function works on a Mac, but does not work on PC. Any thoughts?

Comment: More restriction apply on a PC. Typically the applicationdirectory is a protected area that should only be accessed by administrator so writing to files fails. It is recommended to use applicationstoragedirectory instead.

Answer (score 1):

BotMaster - I found the answer before you posted, but your answer is correct. Add it as an answer, I will delete my post and give you a +1.